# How to mock chrome APIs using JEST framework?

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, jestjs

I want to mock the chrome apis using jest framework. 
For example I am using `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` to send a message to background script. How can I mock `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` or any other apis such as `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to test if the method has been called?

I have tried using jest.spyOn() for testing whether the method has been called.

Here is the test method

```
 test("mock testing chrome",()=>{
     spyOn(chrome,
          chrome.browserAction.setIcon);
     content.chromemocktest();
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({path:"/images.png"});
 });
```

And the method I am testing is :

```
 chromemocktest: function(){
     chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"/image.png"});

 }
```

When I run the `npm run test` for running test cases, it is throwing an error as shown below.

```
 <spyOn> : stub() method does not exist
 Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No, I am sorry. I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the module [@bumble/jest-chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bumble/jest-chrome). I just used it in my TS project, works like a charm, and super easy to use.

Comment: Thank you very much @yuri-drabik. I will check it for sure.

Comment: a bit late to the party, but I am using this one: https://github.com/extend-chrome/jest-chrome

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the chrome object doesn't exist in the nodejs global object.

So you have to create a mock object first:

```
global.chrome = {
   browserAction: {
       setIcon: function () {}
   }
};
```

After that you should be able to spy the object's method:

```
spyOn(chrome, chrome.browserAction.setIcon);
```

If you don't want to create mock for every object of the Chrome API by yourself you can use [the following ready solution](https://github.com/clarkbw/jest-webextension-mock).